# Disable special characters in Aurora MySQL 5.7 full-text search (somehow works in 5.6)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

We are using Aurora MySQL 5.6 and trying to upgrade to MySQL 5.7 but encountered an issue with a full text search.
If the search value contains special characters, then the following error is returned (only on instance, upgraded to 5.7):

```
"syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end"
```

SQL example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH(field_name1, field_name2) AGAINST('+somevalue@gmail.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

We checked different settings and tried to update (to align with the current 5.6 version):

```
innodb_strict_mode = off
sql_mode = IGNORE_SPACE,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

and then rebuilt fulltext index.
Also value for ft_boolean_syntax characters + -><()~*:@""&| is the same on both DBs.
Engine is InnoDB.
But eventually no difference, the same error.

Also I tried to check this using Docker and this issue is reproduced on both MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 containers.

I'm wondering, what setting is responsible for this behavior? How to update/disable it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html says:

> InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of the `@` symbol in boolean full-text searches. The `@` symbol is reserved for use by the `@distance` proximity search operator.

But you can quote the search string and it works (at least in MySQL 8.0.29 which I am testing):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(field_name1, field_name2)
  AGAINST('"somevalue@gmail.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-----------------------------+-------------+
| field_name1                 | field_name2 |
+-----------------------------+-------------+
| abc somevalue@gmail.com xyz | other text  |
+-----------------------------+-------------+
```

If you need to use a `*` metacharacter, this can go inside the quotes.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(field_name1, field_name2)
  AGAINST('"somevalue@gmail.com*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-----------------------------+-------------+
| field_name1                 | field_name2 |
+-----------------------------+-------------+
| abc somevalue@gmail.com xyz | other text  |
+-----------------------------+-------------+
```

If you have other combinations of metacharacters, I'll leave it to you to test.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Though it's not very clear to me about
```
The @distance operator is implemented in MySQL 5.7
```
As it's contained in both versions
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

And it's strange to me that on our current 5.6 DB there is no error, but error is displayed on 5.7 and test DB 5.6 (in Docker).

Comment: Sorry, my example initially was not very precise (I updated it), as we use leading + plus sign and trailing * wildcard operator for each search word, e.g. '+somevalue@gmail.com*' (or it can be just '+somevalue@gm*').

So looks like that quotes will not help here - it returns error
"syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'"